# SpringBoot @DateTimeFormatを使ったバリデーションエラーメッセージを設定できない

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Spring Bootアプリケーションで@DateTimeFormatを使ってExampleForm.java内のDate型のバリデーションを行いたいのですが、messages.propertiesにtypeMismatchを利用してメッセージ定義をしてもメッセージにセットされません。
色々と調べたのですがやり方がわかリませんでした。

解決策を教えていただきたいです。

**ExampleForm.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExampleForm {
  @NotNull(message="searchName is Empty!!")
  private String searchName;

  // このフィールドのバリデーションメッセージを設定したい
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyyMMddhhmmss")
  private Date searchDate;
}
```

**ExampleController.java**

```
@RestController
public class ExampleForm {

  @GetMapping("/example/search")
  public List<String> searchExample(@Validated ExampleForm form) throws Exception {

    // ... 処理 ...

    return list;
  }

}
```

**ExceptionControllerAdvice.java**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
  public List<String> handleExampleBindException(BindException bindEx) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(FieldError err : bindEx.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
      list.add(err.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return list;
  }

}
```

**MessageConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadResourceBundleMessageSource ms = ReloadResourceBundleMessageSource();
    ms.setBeanname("classpath:messages");
    ms.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return ms;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    lvfb.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
  }

}
```

**messages.properties**

```
typeMismatch.java.util.Date=Invalid Date Format.
typeMismatch.exampleForm.searchDate=searchDate of exampleForm is Invalid Date Format.
typeMismatch.searchDate=searchDate is Invalid Date Format.
```

**動作確認コマンド**

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:port/example/search?searchName=xxxxxxx&searchDate=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

補足
デフォルトメッセージに入っているのは以下のメッセージでした。

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'searchDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not parse date: Unparsable date:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

`MessageSource` から対応するメッセージを取得する必要があります。
`getDefaultMessage()` で取得したメッセージはあくまで "*デフォルト*" メッセージです。

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    public List<String> handleExampleBindException(final BindException bindEx) throws Exception {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final FieldError err : bindEx.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            list.add(messageSource.getMessage(err, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Bean Validation(Hibernate Validator) で検証エラーになった場合には `ValidationMessages.properties`(※) で定義したメッセージがデフォルトメッセージになるので `getDefaultMessage()` で期待したメッセージが取得できます。

しかし今回のエラーは Bean Validation を使った処理(validation)でなく、それより前の処理(binding)のものです。

※ デフォルト設定の場合。質問文のコードでは `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` カスタマイズによって `messages.properties` に変更されています。

参考:

- [3. Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/core.html#validation)
- [3.7.3. Configuring a DataBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/core.html#validation-binder)
- ([3.2. Resolving Codes to Error Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/core.html#validation-conversion))

---

質問のデフォルトエラーメッセージを設定しているのは [`DefaultBindingErrorProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.9/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/DefaultBindingErrorProcessor.java#L78-L79) なので、このクラスを置き換える(デフォルトメッセージにあらかじめ所望の文字列をセットするようにする)というのも、別の対応策として挙げられるかと思います。